# Show Document Shared with me in Web Part in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, share

Is there any way to show documents shared with me in a Web Part in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad and does not indicate what technology you are using to build the web part. Here is a general answer. You can view items shared with you on the "Shared with Me" view in OneDrive `https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_domain_com/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?view=3`. You can also use the REST API endpoint on a GET `/me/drive/sharedWithMe`

I suggest you have a look at the OneDrive developer docs and ask additional questions. Post your code attempts too.

[OneDrive API Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_sharedwithme)

Comment: My requirement is to display the 'Shared with Me' files within the Site somehow. I know that user can view them in 'Shared with Me' section in Onedrive. I wanted to know if there is any way to retrieve those document and display in web part or any way to add refiners in Search to display those documents.

Comment: Yes, look at the developer documentation I posted above and use REST in your web part.